# Simplest way to encapsulate multiple method arguments?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

```
+ (Planet *)createPlanetInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context 
                         withName:(NSString *)name 
                             type:(NSString *)type 
                            group:(NSString *)group 
                      andDiameter:(NSNumber *)diameter {
```

If I wanted to encapsulate the arguments "name", "type", "group" and "diameter" into a single entity for passing to the above method what is the best type to use for encapsulation? The above method is just a quick example which you could argue is just fine as presented, but what if there were many more arguments that needed to be passed. I would need to package the data before calling the method so the solution needs to be something quick and simple to setup.

```
+ (Planet *)createPlanetWithData:(Data *)data inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
```

Or is it more inline with objective-c practices (more readable) to individually list all the arguments?

Comment: Personally I'd use a Dictionary. So that you don't have to add the parameters in an exact order(such as array). Just use objectForKey of that dictionary to get the desired parameter

Answer (score 2):

I'd say generally you would want to individually list your arguments, for clarity. The sample method you've posted above isn't terribly long, in the context of Objective-C.

It's really to do with readability and documentation. When you list all the arguments it's clear to developers coming to your project what's being passed in where, and what kinds of objects are floating around. Automatic documentation generation (eg, Doxygen) also works off lists of arguments particularly well.

But there is a point at which, as you say, it becomes a little unwieldy. Twenty parameters to pass in and your method calls are going to be very, very long! So there are other options available - the easiest one is probably to use a `NSDictionary` or similar, which is used already in iOS to ferry certain bits of data around (particularly with notifications, where you have the `userInfo` dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

Reading code is harder than writing code, so optimize for readability. Shortness of selectors should not be a factor; clarity should be.

Ask yourself which version is more readable, and stick to that one. I think it's relatively obvious that the version with the direct arguments is more readable.

Objective-C has wonderful syntax for methods with multiple arguments, so use this to your advantage. In a language with c-like syntax, I'd also hesitate to use many arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could populate a dictionary with one key/value pair per property on your NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be super flexible, you could go with @Novarg's comment and pass a dictionary as  your argument.  That way, you can add parameters to it without affecting your method signature.

I have a particular preference for creating a custom *args* object to pass into my methods.  This not only has the flexibility of a dictionary, but also may have some built-in utilities or additional logic.  Also, unlike a dictionary, you don't need to hardcode key names and/or constants, and is ***MUCH*** easier to refactor if you, say, need to change a name of a property using Xcode's refactoring capabilities:

```
+ (Planet *)createPlanet:(PlanetArgs *)args
{
           //args.context
           //args.name
           //args.type
           //args.group
           //args.diameter   

           //Args can even have some built-in logic
           //planet.color = [args generateRandomColor]; <<-Just a rough idea
}
```